# PHP file upload script fails

Tags: php

I've been following a tutorial for file uploads to my server. The script appears to work, but when I look in the upload directory there's nothing there.

```
<?php

$file_result="";

if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
$file_result .= "No file uploaded or invalid file.";
$file_result .= "Error code: ". $_FILES["file"]["error"]. "<br>";
} else {

$file_result .=
    "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>" . 
    "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>" . 
    "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br>" ;
    "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
    "full/path/on/server" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]); //Actual address removed

    $file_result .= "File Upload Successful!";
} echo $file_result;

?>`
```

The HTML looks like this:`

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload_file.php" method="post">
Browse Files:<br>
    <input name="file" type="file" id="file" size="80"><br>
    <input type="submit" id="u_button" name="u_button" Value = "Upload the File">
</form>
```

`

Comment: Turn on error reporting and start solving the errors, happy debugging.

Comment: destination folder has write permission ?

Comment: you have not used enctype . Please check the form as <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">.... enctype

Answer (score 0):

Use following Code for Upload:

```
if (Isset($_FILES["yourfilename"]["name"])) {
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $target_dir = "Upload/";
    --path
    $tempname = basename($_FILES["yourfilename"]["name"]);
    $target_file = $target_dir.basename($_FILES["yourfilename"]["name"]);
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    if ($tempname != "") {
        if ($_FILES["yourfilename"]["size"] > 20000000) {
            echo "Sorry, Maximum 20 mg.<br>";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        if ($imageFileType != "doc" && $imageFileType != "docx" && $imageFileType != "txt") {
            echo "Soory, Doc-Docx-Txt Only Format  Sopport.<br>";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["yourfilename"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
        }
    }
```

Comment: ***Explain*** what has changed.